# jQuery validate.js only email is not being validated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am using `validate.js` to validate my sign-up form. It works fine with all other fields but I don't understand why it does not affect `email` field.

Here is my validation script:

```
<script TYPE="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signup").validate({
    errorElement: 'div',
    rules:{
        "display_name":{
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        "user_email":{
            required:true,  
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: "user/checkEmail.php",
                type: "post"
            }
        },
        "password":{
            required:true,
            minlength:6
        },
        "confirm_password":{
            required:true,
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        display_name:{
                    required: "Please provide your desired display name",
                    minlength: "Your display name must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },
        user_email:{
                    required: "Please provide a valid email",
                    email: "This is not a valid email!",
                    remote: "Email already in use!"
                    },
         password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long"
                    },
         confirm_password: {
                    required: "Please provide a confirm password",
                    equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                    }
        } 
      });  
     });
 </script>
```

I have tried different ways to make it work but it doesn't.
Here is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" NAME="signup" id="signup" method="post" ACTION="users/register_submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <!-- Form Name -->
                <legend>Sign Up</legend>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <DIV class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" FOR="name">Display Name</label>  
                    <DIV class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="display_name" NAME="display_name" TYPE="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required>
                    </DIV>
                </DIV>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <DIV class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" FOR="email">Email</label>  
              <DIV class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="email" NAME="user_email" TYPE="email" placeholder="example@abc.com" class="form-control input-md" required>  
              </DIV>
            </DIV>

            <!-- Password input-->
            <DIV class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" FOR="password">Password</label>
              <DIV class="col-md-6">
                <input id="password" NAME="password" TYPE="password" class="form-control input-md" required>
                <span class="help-block">At least 6 characters</span>
              </DIV>
            </DIV>

            <!-- Confirm-Password input-->
            <DIV class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" FOR="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
              <DIV class="col-md-6">
                <input id="confirm_password" NAME="confirm_password" TYPE="password" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required>  
              </DIV>
            </DIV>            
            <!-- Button -->
            <DIV class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" FOR="submit"></label>
              <DIV class="col-md-4">
                <input id="submit" NAME="submit" TYPE="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              </DIV>
            </DIV>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Please help me. 
Thanks

**EDIT-UPDATE**
Here is my code for `checkEmail.php`. I have tested it and it is working fine if I test it separately.

```
<?php
require_once("../app/utilities/DatabaseUtility.php"); 
require_once("../app/helpers/DatabaseHelper.php"); 
    function isEmailExists($email){
            $res = array();
            $db = new DatabaseUtility('apex');
            $dbh = new DatabaseHelper;
            $db->connect();
            $col_array = array("user_email");
            $values = array($email);
            if( $statment = $db->prepareStatment('SELECT '.$dbh->getColumns($col_array).' FROM users where user_email = '.$dbh->getPlaceHolders($col_array).'')){
                $db->bindParam($statment, $dbh->getPlaceHoldersArray($dbh->getPlaceHolders($col_array)), $values, $dbh->getBindTypes($values));
                $statment->execute();
                $res = $statment->fetch();
                if(!empty($res)){
                    if(in_array($email,$res)){
                        echo "false";
                    }
                    else
                        echo "true";
                }
                else
                    echo "true";
            }
            else
                echo "Someting is wrong with your query";
            $db->releaseResources();    
        }
    $requestedEmail  = $_REQUEST['email'];
    isEmailExists($requestedEmail);

?>
```

Comment: Could you specify an url to validate.js plugin you're using? I've found 3 different plugins under the same name.

Comment: i am using this cdn http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: I think `type: "request"` should be `type: "POST"` or `type: "GET"` ?

Comment: @user1354678 I have changed it to post now but still no change in result.

Comment: Have you tried for both cases? I mean check the form with both NOT EXISTING EMAIL and EXISTING EMAIL .. If it shows "Email already in use" for not existing email, then you've to change the return value.

Comment: I have tried it either ways, only remote part doesn't works.

Comment: Also, `echo "Someting is wrong with your query";` must be `echo json_encode("Someting is wrong with your query");`  From the documentation, the response from the server (when it's a string) must be JSON encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the id of the email input to: user_email

Edit: I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/66oxokta/ which seems to be working fine. What exactly doesn't work at your solution?

```
    user_email:{
        required: "this works",
        email: "this also works",
        remote: "didnt test this"
    },
```

Comment: which version of validate.js are you using?

Comment: I am using this version http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used your CDN (updated version) and it worked for me.

Comment: but I have another problem. My remote part is not working. Do you know how it works?

Comment: Could you post your checkEmail.php?

Comment: Yes it does, it is working all fine separately but not in remote